# Articles won't show up on Heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my blog app to Heroku but the articles won't show up. It only shows the All articles (h1) on the index page. This app works fine locally with all the articles showing up.

This is what shows up on Heroku:

[image]

This is what I expected to see:

[image]

Comment: Where are the articles supposed to be coming from? A database? Where is that database, and how is the Heroku app connected to it?

Comment: it seems you don't have any record in heroku postgres database,please create record for Article  first.

Comment: how do i create the record in the heroku database. sorry i am asking all these. its all new to me

Comment: did you run this command => heroku run rake db:migrate

Comment: please follow this reference https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5  it should work like a charm for you :) .

Comment: Yes i did. I ran that command after pushing the app to heroku

Comment: press on create a new article button and create record.

Comment: The way the project was set up, only administrators can create new articles. So i tried to login as an administrator but after entering my email and password the page just refreshes.

Comment: `heroku run rails c` access the console => create a user account or make existing user admin => create the article record

Comment: Thank You Very much! I tried Articles.all and Authors.all at the heroku rails console and they both returned an empty array. I figured out that the local articles and authors I created were not included after heroku deployment and the heroku app expected me to create a new author as there was none in the first place. I did that and it worked flawlessly. So I just have to login now and create new articles. Thank you very much again Neeraj and Deepak! I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Many thanks to you too jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is accessing records placed on your local database from a different database stored on heroku's servers.

You need to re-create the records on the production database. You can do this by repeating the exact steps you did on your localhost server.

From the screenshot I can see a red button "Create a New Article", click on this and proceed to create a new article. Once you save this, you will be able to see your article displayed in your All Article page.